# Can you set the permissions for a user when you share an SP site with them (as a member)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, security, sharepoint-permissions, modern-team-site

Scenario:
I create a new team site (without O365 group) from the Admin center. I added a few users to the Member group so they have edit permissions on the site.

**Current behaviour:**

These members are able to share with other users in the org, which is fine. However, when they try to share with other users, my members do not have an option to change the permission for the user they are sharing to. That is, they dont have the dropdown to specify "Edit" or "Read Only". They can only enter the user's name and share the site. The users are added on as members as well (with Edit permissions).

If I log in as a site owner, I can see the dropdown which allows me to specify the permission for the user I am sharing to (i.e. read only or edit).

**Expected Behaviour**
Users in the members group should have option to share an SP site with other users, with read or edit permissions using the drop down.

I am not sure if this is a bug or an issue with my tenant. Has anyone else come across this? Or does anyone have a workaround.

I am SharePoint Online, using Modern Team site (without O365 group).

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom permission level?  Create the custom permission level, create a new SP site group, add users to the group, then give it the custom permission level.  The permission level you are looking for is Manage Permissions.

Comment: With the current permission level, Members are still able to share the site with other users. But it only allows them to share with users, and give them edit permissions, but not read permissions. That is the issue I am facing. 
I am working on a site template, along with power automation so I am trying to automate this into my system

Comment: You need to research creating a custom permission level on your site.  You can create custom permissions levels that are not the same as the default level SharePoint provides.

Comment: Thanks @Taco_Buffet. I know I can definitely create the custom level permission, which works as expected. The confusing part for me was that Site Members have the option to 'Share' a site with others (which to me means adding users to a group). But I what I missed was, Site Members have the ability to add people their the Site Members group, and not to Site Visitors. I guess this is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design when you use the SharePoint online UI "Share site" button.

If we create a new permission level named TestPermission which contains "Manage Permissions" and replace the default **Edit** permission of the Member group:

[image]

Then the Share site will not work in UI:

[image]

Therefore, only the site owner can choose to grant permissions.

Comment: Thanks Julie. I appreciate your response. Is there a reason that a member is able to share the site with other users, and grant Edit permissions only? Users are not able to change the permission level down to read.